# How to shift X and Y axis on a PHP 2-d multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

say I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
$data[0]['country'] = Angola
$data[0]['report'] = Food safety

$data[1]['country'] = Angola
$data[1]['report'] = Police

$data[2]['country'] = Zimbabwe
$data[2]['report'] = Water

$data[3]['country'] = Angola
$data[3]['report'] = Safety

$data[4]['country'] = Tanzania
$data[4]['report'] = Etc...
```

What is the easiest to shift the axes, so that I would have

```
$data['country'][0] = Angola
$data['country'][1] = Angola
$data['country'][2] = Zimbabwe
$data['country'][3] = Angola
$data['country'][4] = Tanzania

$data['report'][0] = Food safety
$data['report'][1] = Police
$data['report'][2] = Water
$data['report'][3] = Safety
$data['report'][4] = Etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach($data as $value){

   $result['country'][] = $value['country'];
   $result['report'][] = $value['report'];
}
$data = $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0; $i < (count($data) / 2); $i++)
{
  $data['country'][$i] = $data[$i]['country'];
  $data['report'][$i] = $data[$i]['report'];
}
```